# UPDATE Capacity using COUNT()

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables which are joined by the following

FLIGHT F,
RESERVATION R,
AIRPLANE A

where F.AirplaneSerialNum = A.AirplaneSerialNum
and F.FlightCode = R.FlightCode

In the airplane table, there is a column to store the maximum capacity of any given plane.

In the reservation table, records of passengers are stored, and the flight they are embarking on is based on the FlightCode

In the flight table, there is a column to store the remaining capacity of any given plane, and each flight is uniquely determined by its FlightCode

Thus, I would like to find a way to update the remaining capacity by taking the values of the original maximum capacity, then get the remaining capacity by doing a COUNT() of the number of times the FlightCode appears in the reservation table

So far I've got the first half to work (setting RemCapacity as the original max capacity)

```
UPDATE FLIGHT F
SET F.RemCapacity = (SELECT Capacity FROM airplane 
WHERE AIRPLANE.airplaneserialnum = F.airplaneserialnum);
```

However i'm stuck trying to minus the number of reservations

```
-- to get the count for number of times the FlightCode appears
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation group by flightcode
```

```
UPDATE FLIGHT F
SET F.RemCapacity = F.RemCapacity - 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation group by flightcode ) WHERE  F.FlightCode = R.FlightCode;

(returns %s invalid identifier SQL error)
```

And also if possible, how can I combine both halves into one query?

Comment: In your last query the subquery will return multiple records - counts of reservation for every flight code, subquery will run first and won't care about the WHERE in the main query. You need to have the WHERE clause inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure, but I think this might do the trick for you, doing all the work in one statement:

```
UPDATE FLIGHT F
SET F.RemCapacity = (SELECT Capacity FROM airplane 
WHERE AIRPLANE.airplaneserialnum = F.airplaneserialnum) - 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation r WHERE  F.FlightCode = R.FlightCode);
```